# creating akka child actor with non-default constructor

Tags: java, akka

Can someone help me with this question.
When using akka with Java , is it possible to create an `akka` childactor with a constructor that takes parameters. Because I know the master actor is responsible for creating childactors. So if we have a child actor that takes parameters in its constructor.

Does it mean that anytime there is a call to the child actor , the master actor has to create a new instance of the child actor in order to pass the parameters to the child actor.

Comment: The docs are your friend: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/untyped-actors.html#Props

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily. Once the actor is created, the user will be able to send messages to that actor directly. If you have a system whereby a new actor must be created to do the work of each message, you are better off letting the supervisor create the actor for you and then having the actor send back the data through the tell() mechanism.

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use the UntypedActorFactory (at least in akka 2.1.2):

```
ActorRef myActor = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
  public UntypedActor create() {
    return new MyActor("...");
  }
}), "myactor");
```

[see the docs here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.2/java/untyped-actors.html) under "Creating Actors with non-default constructor"

Answer (score 3):

As Robert says, once an actor is created you just send messages to it. This is how you can create an actor with parameters, which you can do from another actor:

Since Akka 2.2 UntypedActorFactory has been depricated.

Instead the easiest way in my opinion is to do it like this:

```
ActorRef myActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(MyActor.class, params), "MyActor");
```

Alternatively you can implement Creator like this:

```
static class MyActorC implements Creator<MyActor> {
  @Override public MyActor create() {
    return new MyActor("...");
  }
}
```

See here for more info:

> http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.3/java/untyped-actors.html#untyped-actors-java